# Can't find the right SD card slot

Tags: hardware, sd-card

I just got a Raspberry Pi B+ with a NOOBS SD card, but I can't find the SD card slot. I found the micro SD slot on the bottom of the Pi, but my SD card won't fit. Where do I connect it?

Answer (score 1):

The solution was that it was a micro SD card in an SD card adapter, but it looked like a normal SD card.

Answer (score 0):

RPi B+ uses *micro* SD card so I think you need to use a micro SD card and either clone the data from your existing NOOBS or download the latest one into that micro SD card.

Comment: Maybe it got packaged wrong, because the NOOBS card came in the same package as the Pi but it isn't a micro USB card.

Answer (score 0):

look at the end of the noobs card there shuld be a smaller card you can pull out